# JSON Alignment its looping same item

Tags: java, android, json

i had problem in setting json data its only setting the last item for 4times not able to set other items tried so many ways not able to find it please friends help here

this is the JSON i am using :**http://www.yell4food.com/json/data_standard_item_new.php**

This is the java

```
public class Secondlevel extends Activity {

    List<JSONParser> itemsdata = new ArrayList<JSONParser>();
    String item, ids;
    ListView sec;
    Second_adapter secondAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondlist);
        sec = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.seondlst);
        secondAdapter = new Second_adapter(Secondlevel.this, itemsdata);
        sec.setAdapter(secondAdapter);
        Intent hello = getIntent();
        item = hello.getStringExtra("name");
        new loaditems().execute();
    }
    public class loaditems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String url = "http://www.yell4food.com/json/data_standard_item_new.php";
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rname","standardtakeaway"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cname", item));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cids", ids));
            Calling calling = new Calling();
            String jurl = calling.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
            Log.d("dataurls", jurl);
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jurl);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject first = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
                    parser.setMenuname(first.getString("menu_name"));
                    JSONArray getitems = first.getJSONArray("items");
                    for (int j = 0; j < getitems.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject sitems = getitems.getJSONObject(j);
                        parser.setIid(sitems.getInt("id"));
                        parser.setBaseName(sitems.getString("BaseName"));
                        parser.setItemdesc(sitems.getString("itemdesc"));
                        JSONArray subitems = sitems.getJSONArray("subitems");
                        for (int l = 0; l < subitems.length(); l++) {
                            JSONObject thrid = subitems.getJSONObject(l);
                            parser.setSid(thrid.getInt("id"));
                            parser.setSubItemdesc(thrid.getString("SubItemdesc"));
                            parser.setSubItemprice(thrid.getString("SubItemprice"));
                        }
                        itemsdata.add(parser);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            secondAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Adapter:

```
package com.app.prominere.standardtakeout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by prominere on 20-Oct-15.
 */
public class Second_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    TextView basename,SubItemprice,itemdesc,SubItemdesc;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<JSONParser> items;

    public Second_adapter(Context context, List<JSONParser> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(view==null)
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_clicked, viewGroup, false);
        basename = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.basename);
        SubItemprice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SubItemprice);
        itemdesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemdesc);
        SubItemdesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SubItemdesc);
        JSONParser setdata = items.get(i);
        basename.setText(setdata.getBaseName());
        itemdesc.setText(setdata.getItemdesc());
        SubItemdesc.setText(setdata.getSubItemdesc());
        SubItemprice.setText(setdata.getSubItemprice());
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="BaseName"
        android:id="@+id/basename"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="SubItemdesc"
        android:id="@+id/SubItemdesc"
        android:layout_below="@+id/basename"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="SubItemprice"
        android:id="@+id/SubItemprice"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/basename"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="SubItemdesc"
        android:id="@+id/itemdesc"
        android:layout_below="@id/SubItemdesc"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/order"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/order"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzhfK.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();` inside the **second** for-loop.

Your code will be like that:

```
    JSONObject first = array.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray getitems = first.getJSONArray("items");
    for (int j = 0; j < getitems.length(); j++) {

         JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
         parser.setMenuname(first.getString("menu_name"));

         JSONObject sitems = getitems.getJSONObject(j);
         parser.setIid(sitems.getInt("id"));
         parser.setBaseName(sitems.getString("BaseName"));
         parser.setItemdesc(sitems.getString("itemdesc"));
         JSONArray subitems = sitems.getJSONArray("subitems");

         for (int l = 0; l < subitems.length(); l++) {

              JSONObject thrid = subitems.getJSONObject(l);
              parser.setSid(thrid.getInt("id"));
              parser.setSubItemdesc(thrid.getString("SubItemdesc"));
              parser.setSubItemprice(thrid.getString("SubItemprice"));

         }

         itemsdata.add(parser);
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked for me super yaar i have another doubt can ask please?

Comment: its not applying to other another for loop in the json yaar

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't understand what you mean by *"its not applying to other another for loop in the json yaar"* ?!

Comment: in subitems i have 2 arrays but its displaying one only please check my json "subitems": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "SubItemdesc": "0.33L",
                        "SubItemprice": "0.90"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "SubItemdesc": "1.5L",
                        "SubItemprice": "2.00"
                    }
                ]

Comment: Its taking only the last value of your array, because you use the same `parser` Object inside the third loop.

Comment: i changed the parser to like this JSONParser parser2 = new JSONParser();
                                parser2.setSid(thrid.getInt("id"));
                                parser2.setSubItemdesc(thrid.getString("SubItemdesc"));
                                parser2.setSubItemprice(thrid.getString("SubItemprice"));

Comment: and also can u plz explain when i changed it into 2loop the data displayed it.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not answering specifically to the question but can be used to solve several Gson and Json De-serialization.

well this code can be made easy to use using Gson library, while the objects are populated. Which can be used in code easily.

Make a Response class which will hold menu items

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Response {

@SerializedName("menu_name")
private String menuName;

@SerializedName("items")
private ArrayList<Items> items;

public String getMenuName() {
    return menuName;
}

public void setMenuName(String menuName) {
    this.menuName = menuName;
}

public ArrayList<Items> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<Items> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
}
```

Items.class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Items {

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;

@SerializedName("BaseName")
private String baseName;

@SerializedName("itemdesc")
private String itemdesc;

@SerializedName("subitems")
private ArrayList<SubItem> subItems;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getBaseName() {
    return baseName;
}

public void setBaseName(String baseName) {
    this.baseName = baseName;
}

public String getItemdesc() {
    return itemdesc;
}

public void setItemdesc(String itemdesc) {
    this.itemdesc = itemdesc;
}

public ArrayList<SubItem> getSubItems() {
    return subItems;
}

public void setSubItems(ArrayList<SubItem> subItems) {
    this.subItems = subItems;
}

}
```

SubItem.class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class SubItem {

@SerializedName("id")
private String id;

@SerializedName("SubItemdesc")
private String subItemdesc;

@SerializedName("SubItemprice")
private String subItemprice;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSubItemdesc() {
    return subItemdesc;
}

public void setSubItemdesc(String subItemdesc) {
    this.subItemdesc = subItemdesc;
}

public String getSubItemprice() {
    return subItemprice;
}

public void setSubItemprice(String subItemprice) {
    this.subItemprice = subItemprice;
}
}
```

you can use this class as following to read you entire data and get your objects populated using Gson library

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class MyTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String stringurl = "http://www.yell4food.com/json/data_standard_item_new.php";
    try {
        URL url = new URL(stringurl);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        String result = IOUtils.toString(connection.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("" + result);
        ArrayList<Response> responses = (new Gson()).fromJson(result,
                new TypeToken<ArrayList<Response>>() {
                }.getType());
        for (Response response : responses) {
            System.out.println("" + response.getMenuName());

            ArrayList<Items> items = response.getItems();

            if (items != null) {
                if (!items.isEmpty()) {
                    for (Items items2 : items) {
                        System.out.println("\t"+items2.getId());
                        System.out.println("\t"+items2.getBaseName());
                        System.out.println("\t"+items2.getItemdesc());

                            if (items3 != null) {
                            if (!items3.isEmpty()) {
                                for (SubItem subItem : items3) {
                                    System.out.println("\t\t"+subItem.getId());
                                    System.out.println("\t\t"+subItem.getSubItemdesc());
                                    System.out.println("\t\t"+subItem.getSubItemprice());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This example uses two libraries `commons-io-2.4.jar` and `Gson`

```
Beverages
1
Coca-Cola

    1
    0.33L
    0.75
    2
    1.5L
    1.85
2
Diet Coca-Cola

    1
    0.33L
    0.75
    2
    1.5L
    1.85
```

Comment: tried it but its not displaying the 2nd items in the subitems array

Comment: i am getting errors yaar here getMenuName(),IOUtils

Comment: @AyubBaba, I have updated my answer, after adding those two libraries you should be able to read all json data as you go though the respective objects. this was just an example to understand, I have printed the output of the code

Comment: i am having error here bro getMenuName() and  ArrayList<Response> responses = (new Gson()).fromJson(result,
                new TypeToken<ArrayList<Response>>() {(HERE ITS ASKING TO IMPLEMENT THE METHODS)

Comment: just make a java project in eclipse and add those libraries, put these four classes as it is and it will work

Comment: i am using android studio

Comment: also added the library